# No module named Pygments

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pygments

I have installed Pygments into my virtualenv, and it appears to be imported properly into my project.

[image]

I'm using PyCharm, and I'm getting no import errors from the IDE.

[image]

But when I try to run it on localhost, I get the following error:

[image]

My interpreter is set up like this:
[image]

I get the same issue if I try try to import the whole Pygments module.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: have you added it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Probably You have installed `Django` as a global package too and You don't set virtualenv in PyCharm.

Comment: If i add it to installed apps I get an "Apps aren't loaded yet" error.

Comment: Don't add `pygments` to INSTALLED_APPS. It's not a django app.

Comment: Please don't post code or errors as image. It's text, post it as such.

Comment: I posted the pygments code as an image so I could show that no errors were showing up in the IDE, which I wouldn't have been able to demonstrate with just text.  As for the error log, you're right, I should have posted that as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go ahead and find out which interpreter you're really using when you "run" your application.

First, I'd put this command just before you do the pygments import:
`import sys; print(sys.executable)`

This will give you a good indication of what the python interpreter is using.

If you're running the stuff from inside PyCharm, you might have forgotten to set the project Interpreter. The line above should tell you exactly.

Anyway, going forwards. To set the project interpreter in PyCharm, go to `File > Settings` and you'll see this menu:
[image]

Go to the `Project Interpreter` option (on the left). On the right side of the screen there's the little gear, and if you press on this, you'll see this little menu pop up:[image]

I assume your virtual environment is on your local machine (not in some virtual machine). If this is true, you can just click on `Add Local` (add local python interpreter that is).

In the next menu, assuming your virtualenv lives in the directory `/home/myuser/virtualenv`, go ahead and choose the file `/home/myuser/virtualenv/bin/python`.

That's pretty much it.

Now I assumed you were running the project from PyCharm.

If I was mistaken, and you were running it from the console via a command such as `python -m my_module`, and you're in linux, go ahead and CHECK what `python` interpreter you were using by typing `type python`. This will tell you exactly if that's the python for which you showed us the site-packages.

If it's not, make sure to activate that virtual environment (on linux it's `source /home/myuser/virtualenv/bin/activate`). For windows, google is your friend.

Other stuff that might be happening is that you are using some shell that's a little lazy and even if you had installed the virtual environment, it's still using a python version used previously.
In `bash`, use the command `hash -r`, in `zsh` use the command `rehash`. This will update your shell to know about the new python.

If nothing works, just post your results, and I can tell you what to do from then on.

From your last comments, it appears you might not have been `activated` your virtual environment.

When you `cd` into the directory where you `python manage.py runserver`, you're using the wrong `python`. To check this for yourself, just go to your terminal, and `cd` into the directory that contains your `manage.py` script. Type `python` there. Inside the python console, run this : `import sys; print(sys.executable)`

**[EDIT]**

As previously stated, it will `/usr/bin/python`. That is not the python executable you want.

In order for `python` in that context to refer to the python that has pygments installed, you need to **activate the virtual environment**. This simply means making the command `python` be the one you expect.

This is easily done with this command `source ~/Desktop/Misc/Hobbies/Programming/Projects/Pygamers/venv/bin/activate`

After you run this command, you can type `python manage.py runserver <whatever options you want>` again, and it should work.

If it doesn't, then type `hash -r` (if you're using the bash shell) or `rehash` if you're using zsh. You find out what shell you're using by typing the comand `env | sort`, andl looking for the key `SHELL`.

If it still doesn't work, after activating your virtual env, run the command `type python` and post the result, though if you did everything correctly, there's a 99.99% chance it will work.

Comment: So I used `print(sys.executable)` which returns `usr/bin/python`, which it shouldn't be.  I have the interpreter set in PyCharm to the correct local virtualenv in my project, so I'm not sure how it's using the wrong version.  I added an image of PyCharm showing the interpreter to my question.

Comment: How do you run your application? Pycharm is set up correctly, but the interpreter that actually runs your code is independent of pycharm, and is the one causing you problems. Please share the exact steps you take when running the application. For instance, do you just use the "run" button in pycharm? If so, please put a print screen with your configuration. Maybe you haven't specified the proper interpreter there. Pycharm is complex, it's good to understand python first, and pycharm next, otherwise you get into weird situations like this :D

Comment: I'm running the project through localhost, not in PyCharm.  Could this have some to do with my virtualenv?

Comment: Hosting the project locally has nothing to do with the interpreter. Please post the EXACT steps how you start you application. You need to use the interpreter in your virtual environment, and you're obviously not doing that.... so for instance, after you restart you computer, what are the exact steps you take to try starting the application? Do you double click on something? Do you run a shell command? Do you click on a button in PyCharm? I need the exact steps man :D

Comment: I use terminal to `cd` into the project folder.  I then use `python manage.py runserver` to start the localhost at port 8000.  I then go to localhost:8000 in my browser, where I get a `can't connect to server` error, and the error in my terminal log says `no module named pygments.lexers`

Comment: @TK-421 edited my answer, check it out. I added the step about how to **activate the virtual environment**. You see, you might have a lot of python executables on your system. You need to make sure that when you type `python` in the console, you're using the executable that you want, and not another one.